# Evaluating YUi and BackBone

Tags: html, css, frameworks, backbone.js, yui

I want to start a project and I am evaluating the architecture.

And now I am at point to decide the front end components.

I want to use HTML5 + Css3 + Javascript

On Javascript side I don't know what do you recommend. YUI or Backbone. I don't know how to evaluate what can be the best for me. The idea is to create a Browser web app and a Mobile app.

Do you recommend another framework for do that? Or some book, url or something that expose how to organize my front end?

Answer (score 5):

This might be a bit late.  But I will say this.  I've looked through these so far:

Angular, Knockout, Backbone, YUI

And I read some other comments on Ember.

From what I've seen, Angular and Knockout take the same starting approach.  They start out telling you how to interface with the front end.  I do NOT like this.  They give you a whole lot of rope to hang yourself with if you don't know how to design good architecture.  Its completely up to you to build a proper MVC app with them.

From what I've seen of YUI, its EXTREMELY similar to Backbone, which is no surprise because YUI was INSPIRED by Backbone.  I have spent a LOT of time looking at backbone and I'm very impressed with it.  If you follow its principles and standards, it will encourage you to build a sound framework that won't leave you hanging later.

But I saw another commentor who actually actually moved from Backbone to YUI because he said YUI is more streamlined and all around better.  I wouldn't be surprised if this is true.  But I need to evaluate it further.

Many folks, including myself, agree that Ember, Knockback, and Angular are rather "heavy handed" in their approach.  Like  I said, they START with explaining how to interface with the HTML.   Right out of the gate, they're wanting you to do things a certain way.  This could be very problematic depending on your particular application..  OR it could make your particular application a piece of cake if it fits nicely in their approach!

My two cents!

Answer (score 1):

Backbone is great for creating web apps, both for desktop and mobile. It's strongest point is that it's small and quite simple: you can actually read through the entire annotated source code. Backbone helps you structure your code in a maintainable way, which is the main benefit.

The downside of backbone is that it's not very beginner-friendly: setting up the collections, models and views can be quite challenging if you're not used to it. It also doesn't help you at all in rendering the views, which is a blessing and a curse: it's not as easy or helpful as a widget based framework, but it also doesn't get in your way, which is especially important when implementing the mobile app.

I would recommend you study the backbone todo-example ( http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#examples-todos ) to get an idea how the framework works.